# How to return a partial swagger spec to use in swagger-ui

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

Using this [swagger-ui example](http://petstore.swagger.io/) to ask this question, is there a way to request a portion of the swagger spec's JSON instead of the full thing?

For example, [this url](http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) returns the full swagger spec as JSON for that example. I'm wondering if there's a way to only request the endpoints for the `pet` resource?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Generate a Swagger file for certain endpoints from another Swagger or OpenAPI file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47590562/113116)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to use the [`filter`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#display) option of Swagger UI to filter the displayed operations by `tags`:

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<style>
/* Optional - hide the filter box if needed */
.swagger-ui .filter-container {
  display: none
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function() {

  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
    filter: "pet",  // <------
    ...

</script>
```

If you specifically want to mutate the actual API definition file (.yaml/.json), you would need to implement server-side logic that would do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can write statePlugin that wraps an action updateSpec, actually, here you can modify your swagger file.

```
return {
  statePlugins: {
    spec: {
      wrapActions: {
        updateSpec: (oriAction) => {
          return (spec) => {
            const specObj = JSON.parse(spec);
            // filter or do whatever with your swagger spec here
            return oriAction(JSON.stringify(filteredSpec));
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```