# Generate a Swagger file for certain endpoints from another Swagger or OpenAPI file

Tags: python, rest, swagger, api-design, openapi

Having one big Swagger/OpenAPI YAML specification, how can I safely extract certain API endpoints and generate a new `.yaml` for them exclusively?

It's easy to identify API endpoints from a certain level (like defined with one indent or more):

```
paths:
  /users:
    ...
      - $ref: '#/requests/getUser'
  /repos:
    ...
requests:
  getUser:
    ...
```

I'd just copy all sections, except `paths`, into a new specs file. And then I'd copy certain `paths` subsections like `/users:` based on indents. In Python, with a regex.

But is this direct method safe for the specs?

Comment: You can make data = yaml.load(your.yaml) then just data.get('paths') for get all paths and make yaml.dump later, regex here not required

Comment: Is Python a requirement? This can be done using the Java swagger-parser, but I don't know about Python.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger Inspector lets you make API calls and then create the definition file from them (letting you pick just a subset of calls like you want). See inspector.swagger.io - it's UI-based, but might save you some time.